# Node.js show the index page instead of the request page

Tags: node.js, .htaccess

I start to use Node.js for a while, so I try to use `.htaccess` file to clean the urls and its not worked, so I found that we can use `express-http-proxy` plugin in `app.use` function. so - I build a login page (based on `php`) and when I redirect to this page the page was shown is the index.html page, here`s my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
app.use(express.static('../public'));
app.use('/login', proxy('http://localhost:1234/pages/login.php'));
```

### Solution for this problem:

I changed the url in proxy to my website address, instead of the `server` address (with port `1234`). for example if my server run on `localhost:1234`, on domain `domain.com` you need to put this `domain.com` in the proxy.

Comment: please someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Node does not use htaccess. You could look into [express-htaccess-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-htaccess-middleware) to see if you can proxy your php page through your Node server. I don't know if it can be done though.

Anyway it seems that you're trying to render a local php page through Node/Express (.../pages/login.php). Node only does javascript so it won't be able to render a php page, there is an [express middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express) that does php interpretation (provided php is installed on your server) but I won't advise you to do that.

If you want to serve php pages, it's better to have them hosted on a php server, then if you want to create a proxy from your node to the php server, what I would do is a proxy in express to your php server with [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)

```
    app.use(express.static('../public'));
    app.use('/login', proxy('www.domainOfYourPhpServer/pages/login.php'));
```

Comment: When I do this I got this error: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND locahost locahost:1234
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)`

Comment: Ok so now I see my problem, I wrote `locahost` instead of `localhost`, but its not work.. when I go to `/login` its show me the index.html page..

Comment: Can you update your question with your last attemps to help with the resolution?